# Can't see my wireless printer in the DHCP client list on my router

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, printer

I am using EPSON 900WD printer on wi-fi. I changed the router sometime back. However now I cannot see the printer on the router.

What I have tried:

I tried to open the next available IP on the DHCP client list using a browser. I get the main page of the printer. However I see the printer offline on my laptop.

I also tried assigning a fixed IP (IP reservation) and I get the printer page when I open the printer main page using the assigned reserved IP. The printer is still offline on my laptop.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Using the printer's built-in screen/control panel try re-setting the network settings and re-connect to your wireless...

Comment: I tried this multiple times @BigChris

Comment: Are you saying that the printer added on your computer is a different IP to the one you open in the browser and you get the printer web interface? Try deleting the printer from your computer and re-add with the new IP/let the EPSON software find the device...

Comment: I removed the printer from m laptop now and tried to add it again. But windows cannot find it as it is not available in the DHCP client list (possibly). However, I added the printer now using the IP directly.

Comment: To remove a non-existent printer you need to remove the printer and the port. Try using this tool: Click `Start` -> type `print management` -> expand `print servers` -> expand your computer name -> click `printers` and delete the old printer -> click `ports` and delete any of the `TCP/IP` entries that contain your printer on an old IP. "However, I added the printer now using the IP directly" -> did this work as expected? Is the printer now online and ready?

Comment: @BigChris, I could resolve it. When I searched for printer, I could not find one. Then I opted for connecting to the printer using TCP/IP. I provided the reserved IP and could connect to the printer. It is working fine for me now.

Comment: Grand :) create yourself an answer and mark it as the answer to your question. Don't put the resolution in the question :)

Comment: Does the printer perhaps have a fixed IP address? In that case the router will not have it in the DHCP list, but the printer can still be used. A config page or the printer's web page should tell you where the printer gets its address.

Comment: @hdhondt: Earlier once I added a static IP on the control panel of the printer as the router that I was using then wasn not able to see the printer somehow. However, I set it to dynamic on the printer's panel after I changed the router.

Comment: If the printer uses DHCP, then you MUST make sure the router will not assign it to any other device. If that happens, you will no longer be able to print. The router will have a reservation table in which you enter the printer's MAC address and the IP address you want it to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED the issue to be able to connect to the printer from other devices.**

*Printer is still not visible on the routers DHCP Client list.*

I could resolve it. When I searched for printer, I could not find one. Then I opted for connecting to the printer using TCP/IP. I provided the reserved IP and could connect to the printer. It is working fine for me now.

Comment: To accept your answer as the answer that fixed your problem click the tick to the left (below the votes)